# How are individual primes related to prime distribution?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I happened to be thinking about this today: how individual primes are related to prime distribution. For example, there are many theorems which seem to relate to individual primes rather than the aggregate of all primes taken together, such theorems as Fermat's Little Theorem, the fact that a prime is of the form $3n+1$ iff it can be written as $x^2+3y^2$ (equivalently $x^2+xy+y^2$) for coprime integers $x,y$, or the Quadratic Reciprocity Law.

One thing I have managed to spot is the fact that theorems in the former category seem to come from algebraic number theory whereas theorems about the distribution of primes come from analytic number theory. This would make sense intuitively since algebra is kind of like a discrete version of analysis. Anyway, I don't think I can get far using this kind of (intuitive) thinking alone and was hoping that someone more experienced than I (after all, I have not studied maths at university yet) could shed some light on this?

Comment: The structure of the primes is still a great mystery. Goldbach's conjecture for example is easy to formulate (Every even number greater then $2$ is the sum of two primes , not necessarily distinct), but still open. And we do not know whether $x^2+1$ is prime for infinite many integers, whether infinite many twin primes (two primes with difference $2$ form a twin) exists. And finally, it is unknown whether infinite many Mersenne-primes (of the form $2^n-1$) or whether infinite many Fermat-primes (of the form $2^n+1)$ exist.

Comment: This is surely not a complete list what we do not know about primes and their distribution, but it shows that despite much progress and great results, many open questions remain. What we do know is that every arithmetic progression $an+b$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ contains infinite many primes (Dirichlet), so we can be sure that there are infinite many primes ending with the digits $\cdots 0031027$ or any other digit sequence ending with $1$, $3$, $7$ or $9$. And a mathematician (I do not remember the name) managed to prove that infinite many primes of the form $x^2+y^4$ exist.

Comment: Another important result is that for $n\ge 2$, the interval $[n,2n]$ contains at least one prime (Bertrands postulate)